# Is there any way to make SendInput set the LLKHF_INJECTED flag?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I'm interested to know if there was a way to make `SendInput` set the `LLKHF_INJECTED` flag in a low level keyboard hook. I'm pretty sure macro apps have some way to do this, but I'm not sure how. Is there a C++ Windows alternative, or do I need to configure my `INPUT` differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `SendInput` will set the `LLKHF_INJECTED` flag, as observed by a low-level keyboard hook. You do not need to do anything special. After all, the sole purpose of [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) is to inject input.

This is explicitly spelled out in the [LowLevelKeyboardProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644985(v=vs.85)) documentation:

> If the input comes from a call to `keybd_event`, the input was "injected".

`keybd_event` is the predecessor of `SendInput`.

Comment: Is there any way to *change* the flag set, or *prevent* `SendInput` from calling `keybd_event`? Sorry if the original post was unclear, but I want to "fool" a keyboard hook into thinking this `SendInput` event was sent by the user, not `SendInput`.

Comment: @sup There is no way to inject input without that input being identifiable as injected by a hook. There's no way for you to customize that behavior, regardless of whether you are calling `keybd_event` or `SendInput`. That's just how the system works. If you need your input to look like real input, you're going to have to go with a much more involved solution, like writing your own keyboard driver.